# getting error colab_kernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

Refer to the following code snippet , is argparse is the reason for this error? How can I fix it?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    

    parser.add_argument('--dataset', type=str, default=a_config.DATASET)
    parser.add_argument('--backbone_name', type=str, default=a_config.BACKBONE)
    parser.add_argument('--decoder_name', type=str, default=a_config.DECODER)
    parser.add_argument('--aug_transforms', type=str, default=a_config.AUG)
    parser.add_argument('--loss_fn', type=str, default=a_config.LOSSFN)
    parser.add_argument('--init_lr', type=float, default=a_config.INIT_LR)
    parser.add_argument('--max_iter', type=int, default=a_config.MAX_ITER)
    parser.add_argument('--seed', type=int, default=a_config.SEED)
    parser.add_argument('--var_min', type=float, default=10)
    parser.add_argument('--var_max', type=float, default=400)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    dataset_name = args.dataset
    backbone_name = args.backbone_name
    decoder_name = args.decoder_name
    aug_transforms = args.aug_transforms
    loss_fn = args.loss_fn
    init_lr = args.init_lr
    max_iter = args.max_iter
    seed = args.seed
    var_min = args.var_min
    var_max = args.var_max

    batch_size = a_config.BATCH_SIZE

    save_path = a_config.STORAGE_PATH + "/Results/"
```

But I am getting an error regarding the colab_kernel_launcher.py. The error is pasted below-

```
usage: colab_kernel_launcher.py [-h] [--dataset DATASET] [--backbone_name BACKBONE_NAME]
                                [--decoder_name DECODER_NAME] [--aug_transforms AUG_TRANSFORMS]
                                [--loss_fn LOSS_FN] [--init_lr INIT_LR] [--max_iter MAX_ITER]
                                [--seed SEED] [--var_min VAR_MIN] [--var_max VAR_MAX]
colab_kernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-82e352ae-8667-492d-9b4a-a4e01bfaa758.json
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
```

Comment: I would like to inform that the issue resolve after installing easydict and defining like this     import easydict
    args = easydict.EasyDict({
        "dataset": a_config.DATASET,
        "backbone_name": a_config.BACKBONE,
        "decoder_name": a_config.DECODER,
        "aug_transforms": a_config.AUG,
        "loss_fn": a_config.LOSSFN,
        "init_lr": a_config.INIT_LR,
        "max_iter": a_config.MAX_ITER,
        "seed": a_config.SEED,
        "var_min": 10,
        "var_max":400
})